# How to write custom rake assets:precompile task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, rake

I have IE specific stylesheets in the same folder as general stylesheets. When I run rake assets:precompile all the stylesheets get compiled into 1 big application.css. What can I do so that IE specific stylesheets gets compiled into separate CSS file like application.ie.css. I was thinking of writing my own assets:precompile task, if this is not the best way than what other choices do I have?